# Using filter__in via Foreignkey relationship returns an empty queryset

Tags: django

I'm trying to use the queryset `category_filter` as a [filter__in // Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) for another query `qs_poller`. However, the query returns an empty set.

```
# View

def render_random_poller(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        category_filter = Category.objects.filter(usercategoryfilter__user=request.user)
        # Returns <QuerySet [<Category: Sports>, <Category: Lifestyle>, <Category: Environment>]>

        qs_poller = Poller.objects.filter(poller_category__category__in=category_filter).order_by('-created_on')[:100]
        # Returns an empty set, although the database holds 5 entries matching the category_filter

    else:
        # Get queryset without filter
        qs_poller = Poller.objects.filter().order_by('-created_on')[:100]

    # Query last 100 published Pollers
    items = list(qs_poller)

    # Pick a random Poller
    shuffled_poller = random.sample(items, 1)
    random_poller_id = shuffled_poller[0].poller_pk

    target_url = '/poller/' + str(random_poller_id) + '/'

    return redirect(target_url, request, random_poller_id)
```

```
# Models

class UserCategoryFilter(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories_selected = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


class Poller(models.Model):

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET(get_deleted_user))
    poller_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should filter on the `category`, not the `category` field of the category, so:

```
qs_poller = Poller.objects.filter(
    poller_category__in=category_filter
).order_by('-created_on')[:100]
```

You can also simplify the filtering to:

```
qs_poller = Poller.objects.filter(
    poller_category__usercategoryfilter__user=request.user
).order_by('-created_on')[:100]
```

This will thus construct a query to find all `Poller`s with as `poller_category` a *related* category specified in the `UserCategoryFilter` model that is linked to `request.user`.

Comment: The top solution returns `'Poller' object has no attribute 'poller_pk'` and the the bottom solution returns `Cannot use QuerySet for "Category": Use a QuerySet for "Account".` hmmh weird

Comment: @Jonas: sorry  made a typo at the bottom one. The top one likely has an error further in the code flow. Can you share what happens after the `qs_poller=...` line?

Comment: @Jonas: likely you have a `Poller` object (for example when enumerating over the queryset), where you fetch the `.poller_pk`, but that should be `.pk`.

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering incorrectly in `qs_poller`. By adding an extra `__category` you are actually filtering on the CharField itself, and not the foreign key that you want to filter on.

You want to instead do this:

`qs_poller = Poller.objects.filter(poller_category__in=category_filter).order_by('-created_on')[:100]`